# What is the fastest way to load Textures in XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, xna-4.0

I'm a student using the latest version of Microsoft XNA for learning purposes.

I need to load a whole lot of texture from the Content folder (or more specifically a folder called Tiles inside the Content folder) and I really don't want to type the following code 100 times:

```
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("texture");
```

I realize I could change the names of the files and run through a loop to load them, but this seems inefficient for finding specific tiles if there's a way I could keep the names. I am just looking for a way to load all of these that saves development time.

Also, the files are in .BMP form, if that matters.

Comment: I know thats not an answer for your question but why are you using still xna? its for your study or only for you? xna 4.0 is deprecated since 2013. I would prefer you to use Unity if you want to stay at C#.

Comment: It's for a class. I use Unity and Godot in my free time, but I'm required to use XNA for the class, although it's outdated. It's an entry-level game programming class.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that every texture needs to be loaded at least once.
So using

```
texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("texture");
```

is fine to repeat for different textures, as long as you don't repeat it for the same texture.

I've learned is to load all textures in the `LoadContent()` of game1.cs, that method is only called once at the moment the game starts. So they're all ready to be used for the rest of the game.

There's also a Lazy Loading practice, where the texture is only loaded for when the object appears. But you should be aware that the texture loading won't repeat itself for each object.